# how to pass dynamic id in opentracker() in php and database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am pass dynamic id in **opentracker()** function using php and database.So how can I pass the id dynamic. I have code like

```
  <a style="width: 113px;height: 42px;border: 0px;background-color: transparent;" onclick="openTracker(10,'call')" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="92" height="32" border="0"  src="images/book_now.png"></a>
```

I am define static define id 10 like this

```
 onclick="openTracker(10,'call')"
```

But I have define dynamic id in **opentracker**() function.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it like this:

```
<a style="width: 113px;height: 42px;border: 0px;background-color: transparent;" onclick="openTracker('<?php echo $your_value ?>','<?php echo $your_value ?>')" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="92" height="32" border="0"  src="images/book_now.png"></a>
```

and then get it in you script like this:

```
<script>
 function openTracker(val1, val2)
 {
   //your script to execute
 }
</script>
```